# Bootstrap Navbar dropbown not working instead refreshes page when pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" style="style.css">

<!-- All icons were courtesy of FlatIcon : www.flaticon.com and FreePik : www.freepik.com -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CVV</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap added to the project  -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/bootstrap-5.1.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="script" href="Resources/bootstrap-5.1.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js">

  <!-- Fonts from fonts.google.com -->

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika+Negative&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="Resources/icon.png">

  <!-- "Icon made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com" -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="Resources/binary-code.png" alt="binary-code-img" height="20px" width="20px;">
      Coder
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#projectsButton"
      aria-controls="projectsButton" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Dropdown Navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="projectsButton" role="button"
        data-target="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Projects
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="projectsButton">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</head>
```

This is the code I have been trying to add a dropdown button to using Bootstrap 5, I was able to successfully add the

element Projects as a toggle button but it is not working, when pressed it just refreshes the webpage.

Rest of the navbar working just fine
Even the brand element that is set to reset to home webpage works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `href="#"` and also add `data-target="dropdown"` property to `<a>` tag

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="projectsButton" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    data-target="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Projects
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="projectsButton">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Working example at : https://jsfiddle.net/navnathjadhav/afmth1nu/

Comment: Thank You looks like I had problems linking bootstrap js as well

Comment: also `<head>` tag where closing after `</nav>`